# Servicenow Vs Qualtrics for concurrent user access and update of surveys

Tags: servicenow, qualtrics

I am basically trying to understand what would be the best fit between Servicenow & Qualtrics
as opposed to on prem survey application for the below  requirement and to give a recommendation -

Use case -
A survey is sent from on prem iis application across to 10k users via email link , the respondents have to access the survey immediately. (this concurrent access of thousands of users itself overwhelms the on-prem application and it times out)
Secondly upon accessing the survey , the users would need to enter data and submit the survey . (Again concurrent update of thousands of users which again times out the on prem system)
Ive enquired qith Servicenow  professionals and they seem to be confident that Service now can do the job. But in case of qualtrics , i have received conflicting reports , some have remarked that large no of concurrent accesses and updates could likely slow down qualtrics.
I need to know for sure if qualtrics can efficently cater to the above load or not.
Can we conclude here that ServiceNow might just be the better option specifically for the above scenario.

Also is there any issue in fetching data from qualtrics into powerBI
or from qualtrics into Azure data lake via the webapi calls

Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: This really isn't a stack overflow type question. However, Qualtrics can handle thousands of concurrent survey responses. Response data can be fetched using the Qualtrics REST API.

Comment: thanks , any definitive document that supports this?